# Is there any way to "destringify" input so it can be used like an identifier?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, function-pointers

### Problem

Is it possible to "destringify" a line of input from a file in order to make it act similar to a variable or identifier? An example might help illustrate what I mean:

```
// A few functions, definitions of these don't matter in this example.
void func1();
void func2();
void func3();

// Main function reading a line in from the user
int main() {
  char input[8];
  fgets( input, 8, stdin );
  /* Pretend the newline has been stripped already */
  void(*fn_ptr)();
  fn_ptr = destringify( input );
  fn_ptr();
  return;
}
```

Basically, using the above example, I'm asking how would I "destringify" the input so that fn_ptr points to the proper function (func1, func2, or func3)? Such a function would be useful as it allows me to let the user choose to choose which function to use while being able to use a single function pointer.

### Restraints

1. A lookup table would be hard to implement as I plan on letting users create their own functions, but if that is the only solution, then that's okay.
2. For the same reason, I would prefer to avoid `switch...case` and `if...else`.

Comment: Nope. Such information is lost after compilation. More modern languages often embed some structural information such as class and function names, and in interpreted languages there's usually not even a compilation step involved. But in C... you'll have to match the input against hard-coded strings somehow.

Comment: What you are looking for is a lookup table. Often, it's efficient to implement string based lookup as hash tables; if the set of keys is known at build time, then a very efficient implementation can be carried out (e. g. [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)). Also, in your specific case, you could use your OS's dynamic loading facilities (e. g. `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`) to obtain pointers to dynamically-named functions.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet "Such information is lost after compilation" is mostly true for local variable names; not so much for non-`static` globals (such as OP's functions). Those names the compiler *has to* preserve in order them to be linked against later.

Comment: I was also thinking of letting the user create his own functions, in that case, a lookup table wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no platform-independent way to automatically do this in C. There are a few options available to you, though.

1. Many operating systems support specific functionality to look up the address of a function given its name. In Windows, you can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to do this, for example. This makes your code less portable, but might be what you're looking for. (It's also a massive security concern, but that's a different story.)
2. Another option would be to create some sort of hash table or BST associating a collection of strings with function pointers. You could then have the user specify which function to call by reading the input from the user, looking up that string in the hash table/BST, then calling the invoked function pointer. You need to make sure to manually populate the hash table or BST, which is extra work, but also gives you control over what functions can be called.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but I guess this is the best choice; if I find a better , I'll accept it, but this is probably the best way.